# newbie Linux Shell "for loop" tower arithmetic

Tags: linux, shell, for-loop

I am trying to write a basic code for (tower arithmetic), atleast thats what its called in my language.
I am new, so I need some help

Im gonna explain how it works:
you have to input 2 numbers number1, number2

those have to multiply result=(number1 * number2)

**the result** has to be multiplied with number2 again and +1 on number2 number1=(result * (number2+1))

this has to loop for 5 times

I hope you understand what I mean and someone can help me

Comment: This is not clear for me: "the result has to be multiplied with number2 again and +1 on number2 number1=(result * (number2+1))" can you write it in steps? As a space between *number2* and *number1=* here "+1 on number2 number1=..." is confusing

Comment: ok;

there are number1 and number2 (user should choose those numbers)

number1 and number2 have to be multiplied together

the result that comes out of them should be multiplied with number2+1 each time
like that:
7*2= 14
14*3= 42
42*4= 168
168*5= 840
840*6= 5040

Comment: Updated my answer after your explanation.

Answer (score 1):

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e # stops execution on first error
set -x # adds tracing of execution steps

read -p "Number 1: " number1
read -p "Number 2: " number2

result=$((number1 * number2))

for i in $(seq 1 5)
do
    result=$((result * $((number2 + i))))
done

echo "Result: $result"
```